# $scope.variable executes before it retrieves data from $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to assign a variable -> value retrieved from my $http request.
But the code used for the variable executes first rather than waiting for the http request even after using promise.

I am new to angular however I thought 'promise' should take care of this.
Kindly suggest !

```
.controller('Gym_DetailsController', function($scope, $http, $state, $timeout, providerdetailservice, $location, $ionicScrollDelegate, $window, $rootScope, $q) {

    $rootScope.providerid = $state.params.UPNO;
    $scope.whichProv = $state.params.UPNO;


    var one = providerdetailservice.getdetails($scope.whichProv);
    $q.all([one]).then(function(arr) {
            $scope.providerinfo = arr;
            console.log(arr[0].data[0].AREA);
            $scope.image = arr[0].data[0].ProvImage;
            console.log($scope.image); * * // This gives output as my required answer but SECOND --> Executed Second**
        },
        function(err) {

        }
    ).
    finally(
        function() {
            //Nothing
        })
    console.log($scope.image); * * // This gives output as undefined FIRST --> Executed first**
    $scope.items = [{
        src: $scope.image,
        sub: 'This is a <b>subtitle</b>'
    }]
})
```

Comment: This is probably the best/easiest resource to understand when it comes to promises, and it uses cartoons! http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Comment: Thank you @lux. That was useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your 2nd console.log() runs first because it's not inside of your promise.

Where you are doing

```
$scope.items = [{
   src: $scope.image,
   sub: 'This is a <b>subtitle</b>'
}];
```

$scope.image won't be available yet because the promise hasn't been fulfilled yet. Move this code into the promise and it should work fine.

```
var one = providerdetailservice.getdetails($scope.whichProv);    
$q.all([one]).then(function(arr){
    $scope.providerinfo = arr;
    console.log(arr[0].data[0].AREA);
    $scope.image = arr[0].data[0].ProvImage;
    console.log($scope.image);

    //now try and access $scope.image
    $scope.items = [{
        src: $scope.image,
       sub: 'This is a <b>subtitle</b>'
    }];
}, function(err){}
).finally(function(){ //Nothing });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do and it works great.

```
Service.getData("param1", $scope.otherParam).then(
    function(data){
        console.log(data.data); //hey there it is... :)
        $scope.someOtherfunctionCallback(data.data);
    }
).finally(function(){ console.log("finally done with that crap..."); });
```

My service:

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('Service',['$http','$q',function($http, $q){
var service={};
var getReportMenu = function(){
        //console.log("getting menu...");
        var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method:'GET',               
                url:'http://localhost:8080/API/PATH',               
                cache:true,
                dataType:'json'})
            .then(
                function successCallback(response){
                    defer.resolve(response);
                },

                function errorCallback(response){
                    //TODO: handle this elegantly later.
                    alert("Error!");
                });
            return defer.promise;
        }

return { getReportMenu : getReportMenu }; //Just easy encapsulation.

}
});
```

Comment: this was slapped together quickly from my working app. Excuse any formatting or bracket issues. It should get you pointed in the right direction though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$q.all([one]).then(function(arr) {
            $scope.providerinfo = arr;
            console.log(arr[0].data[0].AREA);
            $scope.image = arr[0].data[0].ProvImage;
            $scope.items = [{
             src: $scope.image,
             sub: 'This is a <b>subtitle</b>'
            }]
            console.log($scope.image); * * // This gives output as my required answer but SECOND --> Executed Second**
        },
        function(err) {

        }
    ).
    finally(
        function() {
            //Nothing
        })
    console.log($scope.image); * * // This gives output as undefined FIRST --> Executed first**
    $scope.items = [{
        src: $scope.image,
        sub: 'This is a <b>subtitle</b>'
    }]
```

Comment: update $scope.items = [{
             src: $scope.image,
             sub: 'This is a <b>subtitle</b>'
            }]
in your promise call back